# Ошибки при проверке приложения для внутреннего тестирования Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Есть рабочее приложение в Google Play с последним обновлением около 10 дней назад.
Вчера попробовал сделать сборку для внутреннего тестирования и тут же получил отказ. При этом не могу понять, что от меня требуется...
[image: Отказ публикации]

Имя разработчика в консоли указано, в сборке его просто негде указывать, странно...
Иконка высокого разрешения лежит в android/app/src/main/web_hi_res_512.png
Имя приложения то же самое, что и у рабочей версии, ничего не изменено...
Народ, помогите разобраться! Спасибо!

Comment: там же написано что предыдущая версия приложения все еще доступна будет в маркете а это не есть хорошо, я думаю они хотят чтобы вы удалили рабочую версию из маркета, и тогда вы сможете тестировать

Comment: бездушный алгоритм гугла решил, что вы выдаёте себя за другое лицо. Если не смените имя/иконку приложения/имя разработчика - вам забанят и приложение и аккаунт навсегда. Вряд ли у вас получится что-то доказать им. Сочувствую.

Comment: Если захочу обновить рабочее приложение, та же история будет? Тоже подумают, что я другое лицо?